# How many data points are needed for statistical significance using a predictive model?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, forecasting

I have 348 months of asset price data.The range of returns for the data set is -3.47% to 7.40%.Standard deviation is 5.45%. The predictive model has 9 parameters. Do I have enough monthly data to be 99% confident that returns in the future will range between -5% to 5%.

Comment: Did you check that your dependent variables is stationary? If your dependent variable contains an unit root, then statistical significance may be overstated (even with infinite sample size)

Answer (score 1):

Predictive limits on a forecast for k periods out are usually based upon the standard deviation of the residuals from an adequate  arima model and the form of the arima model (via the psi weights). Standard implementation (meaning nearly always inadequate !) assumes that the estimated model parameters are the global parameters and that any pulses that have been identified in the past will not re-occur in the future. You might want to look at http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/blog to review confidence limits (predictive limits) for forecasts . I hate to be the grinch that stole Christmas but Virginia/Ken there is no Santa Claus nor any simple but correct way to answer your question. Simple questions, like yours, sometimes require complicated answers. Your question is stated simply but the correct/adequate answer is complicated and unanswerable without your data.